# How do i add the count of a set of dates to the next date in Excel to the next date

Tags: excel, countif

[Screenshot of the excel date column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Xn9.png)

I am trying to add the count of the date to the next date cells. (looking for a formula). 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the formula to do so is:

```
=COUNTIF(F:F;F2)
```

This is if your data starts on Row 2 and the Dates are all on column F.